# Отправка почты с помощью модуля MIMEImage с вложенным файлом

Tags: python, изображения, email, sendmail, mime

**Как** отправить файл(картинку) на почту(gmail) используя модуль MIMEImage ?

Comment: вы не хотите как MimeText отправлять, вы вероятно хотите как (MIMEImage) `image/*` mime type отправить. Вот [пример для картинки, которая прямо внутри письма показывается](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20485764/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короткий пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html):

```
# Open the files in binary mode.  Let the MIMEImage class automatically
# guess the specific image type.
with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
msg.attach(img)
```

Полный пример:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Here are the email package modules we'll need
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

COMMASPACE = ', '

# Create the container (outer) email message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
# me == the sender's email address
# family = the list of all recipients' email addresses
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(family)
msg.preamble = 'Our family reunion'

# Assume we know that the image files are all in PNG format
for file in pngfiles:
    # Open the files in binary mode.  Let the MIMEImage class automatically
    # guess the specific image type.
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    msg.attach(img)

# Send the email via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Comment: Мне нужен пример именно с почтой, я пробовал переделывать пример из документации что он работал с почтой , но не получилось

Comment: @True-hacker, например: `s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.ru')`. Адрес и порт нужно и почтового сервера смотреть. Я подобное делал для mail.ru https://github.com/gil9red/ordering_lunch_at_Nashe_Vse/blob/0afaddd6233342da8c6dddcbc773a69d36e42d71/api.py#L463

Comment: Я это делаю на gmail . Только тут нужно регистрироваться типо такого: smtpObj.login('название_почты@gmail.com','пароль') , а потом вот так отправлять сообщение: smtpObj.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string()) . Вот только приходит на почту пустое сообщение. Я сначала подумал что это связано с тем , что я отправляю email как строку , но если убрать as_string() - будет ошибка , если дописать as_bytes() - пустое сообщение...

Comment: Вы не знаете , как это сделать на Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл похожий ответ, и немного изменил под gmail : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070038/attachment-image-to-send-by-mail-using-python

Код:

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


def SendMail(ImgFileName):
    me             = 'example@gmail.com'
    you            = 'example2@gmail.com'

    img_data       = open(ImgFileName, 'rb').read()
    msg            = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
    msg['From']    = me
    msg['To']      = you

    text    = MIMEText("Text")
    image   = MIMEImage(img_data, name=os.path.basename(ImgFileName))
    msg.attach(text)
    msg.attach(image)

    s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login("example_email@gmail.com","example_password")
    s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())#Или же msg.as_bytes()
    s.quit()


SendMail("path_to_you_photo")
```